# Как инициализоровать переменную до ее создания?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. 
Если открыть сайт, первым делом выполняется код, который записывает в куки определенное значение:

```
 setcookie('param', '1', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, "/");
```

И на этой же странице, я вывожу записанное значение:

```
echo $_COOKIE['param'];
```

И если зайти на эту страницу в первый раз, получается уведомление:

> Notice: Undefined index: param

После обновления страницы все работает как надо.
Это из-за того что в куках, при первом запуске страницы нет параметра **param** .

каким образом можно это решить?

Comment: А что вы хотите добиться вообще? Ну если её еще нет, а вам обязательно нужно выполнить какую-то операцию - то и выполните её

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мне нужно проверить, есть ли у пользователя в куках запись с **param** = 1 , если да, выполняем код, если нет не выполняем код. при проверке выдается такое же уведомление

Comment: Ну так `if (isset($_COOKIE['param'])) { // do smth  }`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну так я так и делаю, и получаю Notice: Undefined index: param

Comment: Я `isset` куда-то потерял. Нужно через него

Comment: Не забудьте, что куки посылаются от юзера на сервер, и если вы только что сказали юзеру их записать, то сразу в этом же запросе вы их не прочитаете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно, для обхода этой ситуации, просто проверяют существование переменной, и обращаются к ней только, если она существует

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['param'])) echo $_COOKIE['param'];
```

Comment: то что нужно. спасибо